# Allow one character edits on this website

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is wrong with single character edits?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/895/what-is-wrong-with-single-character-edits)

It's fairly impossible to make spelling corrections if there's only one error in the post, and unlike the other SE sites, spelling is of paramount importance here.

Comment: Please see: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/895/what-is-wrong-with-single-character-edits

Comment: This is a feature request; it should not be considered a duplicate of a discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I agree: while I understand the reason for this restriction, I think it is impractical. The cure is simply worse. Besides, it can be circumvented by html comments and other tricks—so I have been told. The restriction should be removed.

Answer (score -1):

The reason a single character edit is not allowed on EL&U is not different from the reason it is not allowed on other SE sites. For example, one user could notice that the name of a C# class in a question on Stack Overflow (or Programmers) is misspelled, but users without the privilege of editing posts are not allowed to make that single change.

It is true, the spelling on EL&U is important, but consider that:

- If there is a word that is not correctly spelled, then there is probably another word that is not correctly spelled.
- If there is just a misspelled word, then there is probably something else that needs to  be changed, like punctuation, the greetings added at the beginning of question, etc.

The other reason single character edits are not allowed is probably to avoid a user gets reputation for just changing a single character.

Comment: The other reason is that it takes a second user to approve the edit. Wasting another user's time is rude.